# Pointers of several functions

Tags: c++, c

Is there any guarantees that the functions which differs only by its names (not parameters and return type also) can't share the same address in C and C++? I don't see anything about it in the standard.

```
#include <cassert>

void foo() {}

void bar() {}

int main()
{
    assert(foo != bar);
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The C++11 standard says

> **5.10 Equality operators**
>   Pointers of the same type (after pointer conversions) can be compared for equality. Two pointers of the same type compare equal if and only if they are both null, both point to the same function, or both represent the same address (3.9.2).

If you don't have any pointers to the functions, they just might have the same address, but we wouldn't know. If you *are* comparing pointers to two different functions, they must not compare equal.

---

One cause for confusion might be that the MSVC compilers are known to combine code for template functions that happen to produce identical machine code for different types (like `int` and `long`). This is not compliant.

However, this is for functions with *different* signatures, and not exactly what this question is about.

Comment: The last comment doesn't make sense now. For different argument types, you have different function pointers, so the rule about "Two [function] pointers of the same type" no longer applies.

Comment: That's true. It's more about a case where we have seen that different functions *can* get the same address, but not really what the question asked about,

Answer (score 3):

Yes. C99 6.5.10:6

> **Two pointers compare equal if and only if** both are null pointers, **both
>   are pointers to the same** object (including a pointer to an object and
>   a subobject at its beginning) or **function**, …

Edit: the rest of the paragraph, since it turns out to have some importance:

> both are pointers to one past the last element of the same array
>   object, or one is a pointer to one past the end of one array object
>   and the other is a pointer to the start of a different array object
>   that happens to immediately follow the first array object in the
>   address space.

What I take from it:

- equality applied to the wrong operands is, in so many words, unspecified. It can be accidentally true for extraneous reasons but it is not undefined when you use it wrong the way `<` is undefined when you use it wrong.
- to the best of my understanding, the rest of the paragraph does not apply to functions, because a function neither is an object nor can it be an element of an array.

Comment: Then shouldn't the implementation assure that they are -actually- the same function? I mean, it's nice that compilers optimize this but language-spec functions seem different to me than post-compile assembly functions.

Comment: Taken from Bo's answer, the last part is "or both represent the same addres". Would the last part of this quote be similar?

Comment: @DanielSloof I think that depends on what comes after the `...`.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: "... or both represent the same address.". But (with my limited C++ knowledge) I am assuming the spec does not clarify on when two functions represent the same address. Tricky business

Comment: @LuchianGrigore: I just read your answer, nevermind the above ;)

Answer (score 2):

Many compilers with optimizations turned on will make two functions have the same address. For example, from [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> /OPT:ICF **can result in the same address being assigned to different
>   functions** or read only data members (const variables compiled with
>   /Gy). So, /OPT:ICF can break a program that depends on the address of
>   functions or read-only data members being different. See /Gy (Enable
>   Function-Level Linking) for more information.

**ICF**: Identical Code Folding

Answer (score 1):

Implementation details.

> (C99, 5.1.2.3p1) "The semantic descriptions in this International Standard describe the behavior of an abstract machine in which issues of optimization are irrelevant."

Comment: The quote is vacuously true. The question is about a real compiler, which differs from abstract machines, but which (even in the presence of optimization) must show the same observable behavior as one of the allowed abstract machines.